# do not show new created rocrd in sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

My Model.js is:

```
await City.create({
  title: req.param('title'),
  ostan_owner: req.param('ostan')
},function(err,new_city){
  if (err && err.invalidAttributes) {
    err = validator(City, err);
    return res.json({'status': false, 'errors': err.Errors});
  }
  console.log(new_city);
  return res.json({'status': true, 'result': new_city});
});
```

when i create a new record of City i store this new record in new_city variable And return the output as json response

But why new_city variable is {} empty while new created record saved in data base???!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `async/await`, you should use it like this :

```
try{

var new_city = await City.create({title: req.param('title'),ostan_owner: 
      req.param('ostan'}).fetch();
      console.log(new_city);
      return res.json({'status': true, 'result': new_city});
   }

catch(err){

      if (err.invalidAttributes) {
         err = validator(City, err);
         return res.json({'status': false, 'errors': err.Errors});
         }
      return res.serverError(err); // if it's not a validation error you should send a response eventually

 }
```